# Error when creating an sqlite statement in ionic 4

Tags: sqlite, ionic4

I am following a tutorial on IONIC 4 CRUD. When I get to the sql statement, I get an error like so:

```
> Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'. 
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]':
> length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts
```

This is the statement where I get the error:

```
db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expense(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, type TEXT, description TEXT, amount INT)', {})
db.executeSql('SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalIncome FROM expense WHERE type="Income"', {})
db.executeSql('SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalExpense FROM expense WHERE type="Expense"', {})
```

I get the red line on the "{}"

[image]

This is the whole code:

```
getData() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ionicdb.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expense(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, type TEXT, description TEXT, amount INT)', {})
      .then(res => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
      db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM expense ORDER BY rowid DESC', {})
      .then(res => {
        this.expenses = [];
        for(var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {
          this.expenses.push({rowid:res.rows.item(i)
            .rowid,date:res.rows.item(i).date,type:res.rows.item(i)
            .type,description:res.rows.item(i).description,amount:res.rows.item(i).amount});
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
      db.executeSql('SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalIncome FROM expense WHERE type="Income"', {})
      .then(res => {
        if(res.rows.length>0) {
// tslint:disable-next-line: radix
          this.totalIncome = parseInt(res.rows.item(0).totalIncome);
          this.balance = this.totalIncome - this.totalExpense;
        }
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
      db.executeSql('SELECT SUM(amount) AS totalExpense FROM expense WHERE type="Expense"', {})
      .then(res => {
        if(res.rows.length>0) {
// tslint:disable-next-line: radix
          this.totalExpense = parseInt(res.rows.item(0).totalExpense);
          this.balance = this.totalIncome - this.totalExpense;
        }
      });
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing `[]` not `{}`.

Look at the [Ionic Native page example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite):

```
db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', [])
  .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```